# Anyone explain left value and right value in Assembly language level？

Tags: c++, c, lvalue

I think everyone here knows that `--i` is a left value expression while `i--` is a right value expression. But I read the Assembly code of the two expression and find out that they are compiled to the same Assembly code:

`mov         eax,dword ptr [i]

sub         eax,1

mov         dword ptr [i],eax`

In C99 language standard, An lvalue is defined to  an expression with an object type or an incomplete type other than void.

So I can ensure that `--i` return a value which is an type other than void while `i--` return a value which is void or maybe a temp variable.

However when I give a assignment such as `i--=5`, the compiler will give me an error indicating `i--` is not a lvalue, I do no know why it is not and why the return value is a temp variable. How does the compiler make such a judgement? Can anybody give me some explanation in Assembly language level？Thanks!

Comment: lvalue and rvalue stands for load value and read value. Not left and right.

Comment: isn't `i--= 5` kind of ambiguous? It could mean `i--  =  5` or `i-  -=  5`

Comment: it is not ambiguous.if it mean `i- -= 5`, how to explain this part `i-`?

Comment: @user93353: Per C 1999 6.3.2.1, note 54, “lvalue” originates in the left side of an expression, and it is used to locate an object. Of particular interest is storing to (not loading from) an object. That is what distinguishes an lvalue: It can be used to modify an object, not merely to retrieve a value.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart: The language parser follows the Maximal Munch principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch). It is required to munch as much as possible from left to right as long (and only as long) as the resultant token is valid. When parsing `i--=5` it will munch `i` as the first token. And then, since there's such valid token as `--` in C and C++, it is required to munch off the whole `--`. It is not allowed to stop after the first `-`. For this reason it will interpret `i--=5` as `i -- = 5`, not as `i - -= 5`.

Answer (score 8):

Left value? Right value?

If you are talking about *lvalues* and *rvalues*, then the property of being lvalue or rvalue applies to the *result* of an expression, meaning that you have to consider the results of `--i` and `i--`. And in C language *both* `--i` and `i--` are rvalues. So, your question is based on incorrect premise in the realm of C language. `--i` is *not* an lvalue in C. I don't know what point you are trying to make by referring to the C99 standard, since it clearly states that neither is an lvalue. Also, it is not clear what you mean by `i--` returning a `void`. No, the built-in postfix `--` never returns `void`.

The lvalue vs. rvalue distinction in case of `--i` and `i--` exists in C++ only.

Anyway, if you are looking at mere `--i;` and `i--;` expression statements, you are not using the results of these expressions. You are discarding them. The only point to use standalone `--i` and `i--` is their side-effects (decrement of `i`). But since their side-effects are identical, it is completely expected that the generated code is the same.

If you want to see the difference between `--i` and `i--` expressions, you have to use their results. For example

```
int a = --i;
int b = i--;
```

will generate different code for each initialization.

This example has nothing to do with lvalueness or rvalueness of their results though. If you want to observe the difference from that side (which only exists in C++, as I said above), you can try this

```
int *a = &--i;
int *b = &i--;
```

The first initialization will compile in C++ (since the result is an lvalue) while the second won't compile (since the result is an rvalue and you cannot apply the built-in unary `&` to an rvalue).

The rationale behind this specification is rather obvious. Since the `--i` evaluates to the *new* value of `i`, it is perfectly possible to make this operator to return a reference to `i` itself as its result (and C++ language, as opposed to C, prefers to return lvalues whenever possible). Meanwhile, `i--` is required to return the *old* value of `i`. Since by the time we get to analyze the result oh `i--` the `i` itself is likely to hold the *new* value, we cannot return a reference to `i`. We have to save (or recreate) the old value of `i` in some auxiliary temporary location and return it as the result of `i--`. That temporary value is just a value, not an object. It does not need to reside in memory, which is why it cannot be an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

[Note: I'm answering this from a C++ perspective.]

Assuming `i` is a built-in type, if you just write `--i;` or `i--;` rather than, say, `j = ++i;` or `j = i++;`, then it's unsurprising that they get compiled to the assembly code by the compiler - they're doing the same thing, which is decrementing `i`. The difference only becomes apparent at the assembly level when you do something with the result, otherwise they effectively have the same semantics.

(Note that if we were thinking about overloaded pre- and post-decrement operators for a user-defined type, the code generated would not be the same.)

When you write something like `i-- = 5;`, the compiler quite rightly complains, because the semantics of post-decrement are essentially to decrement the thing in question but return the old value of it for further use. The thing returned will be a temporary, hence why `i--` yields an r-value.

Comment: Thanks for your answering.`i--`is a r-value, it is a c++ language compile rule, right?;)

Comment: @jaurung: The language specifies that `i--` is an r-value in this case, yes. The compiler just enforces that.

Answer (score 0):

The terms “lvalue” and “rvalue” originate from the assignment expression `E1 = E2`, in which the left operand `E1` is used to identify the object to be modified, and the right operand `E2` identifies the value to be used. (See C 1999 6.3.2.1, note 53.)

Thus, an expression which still has some object associated with it can be used to locate that object and to write to it. This is an lvalue. If an expression is not an lvalue, it might be called an rvalue.

For example, if you have `i`, the name of some object, it is an lvalue, because we can find where `i` is, and we can assign to it, as in `i = 3`.

On the other hand, if we have the expression `i+1`, then we have taken the value of i and added 1, and we now have a value, but it is not associated with a particular object. This new value is not in `i`. It is just a temporary value and does not have a particular location. (To be sure, the compiler must put it somewhere, unless optimization removes the expression completely. But it might be in registers and never in memory. Even if it is in memory for some reason, the C language does not provide you for a way to find out where.) So `i+1` is not an lvalue, because you cannot use it on the left side of an assignment.

`--i` and `i++` are both expressions that result from taking the value of `i` and performing some arithmetic. (These expressions also change `i`, but that is a side effect of the operator, not part of the result it returns.) The “left” and “right” of lvalues and rvalues have nothing to do with whether `--` or `++` operator is on the left side or the right side of a name; they have to do with the left side or the right side of an assignment. As other answers explain, in C++, when they are on the left side of an lvalue, they return an lvalue. However, this is coincidental; this definition of the operators in C++ came many years after the creation of the term “lvalue”.